# Format credit card input JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a form and I ask for the user's credit card, after the input is left I would like to show the cc number like this: **xxxxxxxxxxxx1111** or **xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1111** but without changing the input real value. Is possible to do this with javascript?

Comment: change the input value, on submit do a string replace and remove the dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an '`<input type="hidden">`' to save the `cc` number. That will automatically be posted to your server, when you submit the form.

Now you can change the visible input value to what you want.

To only show the last 4 digits (assuming the id of the visible input is `'cc'` and the hidden input is `'hiddencc'`):

```
var cc = $('#cc').val();
$('#hiddencc').val(cc);
var visblecc = cc.substr(cc.length - 4);
$('#cc').val('xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-' + visiblecc);
```

Now in server side code, check for `'hiddencc''` value.